# Determine if content in editText is a "." ONLY

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have written a calculator type app. My mates found that entering single decimal points only into the `editText`'s makes the app crash. Decimal numbers and integers work fine, but I get a number format exception when `.`'s are entered.

I want to check if a single `.` has been placed in an `editText`, in order for me to display a toast telling the user to stop trying to crash the app.

My issue is that a `.` doesn't have a numerical value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat .1 as 0.1 by the following.

```
String text = et.getText().toString();
int len = text.length();

// Do noting if edit text just contains a "." without numbers
if(len==0 || (len==1 && text.charAt(0).equals(".")))
    return;

if(text.charAt(0).equals(".") && text.length() > 1) {
    text = "0" + text;
}
// Do your parsing and calculations
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it in a `try/catch` which should be done anyway when parsing text. So something like

```
    try
    {
        int someInt = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
        // other code
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        // notify user with Toast, alert, etc...
    }
```

This way it will protect against any number format exception and will make the code more reusable later on.